# H2 Database delete query taking long time

Tags: database, h2

I am using embedded H2 database(1.4.185) in my application. and one table which has around 50 thousand row's, trying to delete data using delete query  is taking >20 min. I tired to drop of table and same performance issue is observed

Any Suggestion How can i do delete operation in seconds?

Answer (score 2):

H2 1.4.185 Beta is a very old beta-quality unsupported version, you really should consider an upgrade first. You need to export your data into SQL script with `SCRIPT TO 'filename.sql'`, create a new empty database with a some recent version of H2 suitable for your needs, and populate it with `RUNSCRIPT FROM 'filename.sql'`.

With any version of H2 the fastest way to delete all rows is [`TRUNCATE TABLE tableName`](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#truncate_table) command, but it has some restrictions.

Most likely your current database is highly fragmented, you can try to defragment it with `SHUTDOWN` command with some data compaction option, but I suggest you not to rely on any operations in these beta versions.